# Matlab image classification by colors

Tags: matlab

I have two diferent satelital images with diferent bands. What I want to see is the difference between the pixels. For achieve that, I've substracted the values of the two images. As a result, I have a new one image with the difference values ​(in the case of a band). I do not know if it would be possible but I would classify this values in colors. For example, if the difference is from 0 to 20 I want that the pixel will be couloured as blue, green if it goes from 30 to 40 and red if it's higher than forty. Is it possible to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
img=rand(300,200)*256; // test image
image(img)
colorbar
```

will show your your image with the default color map, which, as you can see from the color bar, uses various shades of blue for values close to 0, green for values around 120 and red for the highest values.

Note that `image` takes a matrix with values from 0 to 255 as argument, while the default color map contains 64 entries, so each will be used for four ajacent values. The colormap may have 256 rows as well, however.

Just redefine that colormap, like so:

```
myMap = [repmat([0 0 1],20,1); ... %# blue for first 20 values
         repmat([0 1 0],20,1); ... %# green for next 20
         repmat([1 1 0.5],216,1)];  %# bright yellow for the rest
colormap(myMap);
```

(This is assuming your image values are scaled from 0 to 255. If there are fewer rows in the colormap than here are values in the image, the colormap will be scaled and the labels in the colorbar will not match the image values. You may however create a colormap with a number of rows corresponding to the highest value (if <=255) in the image so that it will match. Refer to the help of `image` and `colormap` for details if unsure.)

Comment: Thankyou arne! I have problems because the values are from 0.001 to 1 and I tried to change it but I don't get the exactly result (I've multiplied the image *256 also)

Comment: @user1578688 What is the problem? Is it with the highest values? (Try multiplying by 255 then.) Or that too many low values are grouped together? (Then maybe do a nonlinear scaling, e.g. taking the square root of the values before multiplying by 255. The labels of the colorbar can also be set manually, if needed.)

Comment: Hi! The highest value is 500 (the values are from 0 to 500). image(roug)
colorbar
myMap = [repmat([0 0 1],50,1); ... %# blue for first 20 values
         repmat([0 1 0],180,1); ... %# green for next 20
         repmat([1 1 0.5],500,1)];  %# bright yellow for the rest
colormap(myMap); The problem is the first color is repeated.